# Django REST Framework -- update view method never called

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am designing an API endpoint using Django REST Framework, and would like for it to accept GET, PATCH, and PUT methods at the following endpoint:

```
/department/<department_pk>/details/population/
```

there is a 1:1 relationship between the Department model and the DepartmentPopulationDetail model (the `DepartmentPopulationDetail` model has a FK called `departmnet`). The GET method should return the `DepartmentPopulationDetail` model instance, and PUT and PATCH should allow one to edit that same instance (without needing to provide the `DepartmentPopulationDetail` PK).

I've managed to have the endpoint return the desired response for GET and not allow DELETE or CREATE, but can't get it to accept PUT or PATCH requests -- in fact, the `update` method is never called. How can I get my view to accept PUT and PATCH requests and to edit the appropriate model?

```
urls.py
...
url(r'^departments/(?P<department_pk>[0-9]+)/details/population',
        include(department_urls.department_study_population_router.urls,
        namespace='department_study_population')),
...


serializers.py

class DepartmentStudyPopulationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = DepartmentStudyPopulation
        fields = ('pk', 'department', 'age', 'zip_code')
        read_only_fields = ('pk', 'department')

views.py
class DepartmentStudyPopulationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = DepartmentStudyPopulation.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DepartmentStudyPopulationSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'put', 'patch']

    def update(self, request, department_pk, **kwargs):
        queryset = departmentStudyPopulation.objects.all()
        study_population = get_object_or_404(queryset, department_pk=department_pk)
        serializer = DepartmentStudyPopulationSerializer(
            study_population, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Can you post your router as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why the `update()` method never gets called**?

This is because you have incorrectly defined the urls.

This url

```
'departments/(?P<department_pk>[0-9]+)/details/population'
```

with router generates the following urls.

```
'departments/(?P<department_pk>[0-9]+)/details/population/' # handle list views
'departments/(?P<department_pk>[0-9]+)/details/population/<pk>/' # handle detail views
```

So, your `update()` method will only be called when there is a request on the below url where `pk` represents the `id` of `DepartmentStudyPopulation` object.

`'departments/(?P<department_pk>[0-9]+)/details/population/<pk>/'`

**How to handle the `update` and `retrieve` requests on the desired url then?**

You need to make some changes to handle both `update` and `retrieve` requests on the below desired url endpoint.

```
/department/<department_pk>/details/population/
```

Firstly, you should use [`RetrieveUpdateAPIView`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveupdateapiview) instead of `ModelViewSet` as you need to handle only `detail` routes. This generic view will only permit `GET`, `PUT` and `PATCH` methods.

Secondly, you are getting the object instance using the `department_pk` url kwarg by filtering on the `department_pk` field and not the `pk` field of `DepartmentStudyPopulation` object. You should just specify the `lookup_field` and `lookup_url_kwarg` with value as `department_pk` in your view and DRF will handle the instance retrieval.

**Final Code:**

**views.py**

```
class DepartmentStudyPopulationDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):

    queryset = DepartmentStudyPopulation.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DepartmentStudyPopulationSerializer
    lookup_field = 'department_pk'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'department_pk'
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^departments/(?P<department_pk>[0-9]+)/details/population', DepartmentStudyPopulationDetailView.as_view())
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a different URL to handle those cases.

Create means that your DepartmentStudyPopulation is new, and won't have a primary key (it gets generated on createion).

Update will require a url that has the primary key in it, so that Django knows what object to update.

(Showing the URL's file would be helpful for this question, as we have no idea where they are routing to).